# Python CGI Cookies

Tags: python, cookies, cgi

I have a question. I am coding a python CGI script in which i have to change the background and foreground colors using html input. I am suppose to implement cookies. The problem i am facing is that i can change as many background colors as i want, but when i enter any foreground color, i cannot do any more changes with the inputs and i have to restart the application again. Here is my code:

```
<pre>
<code>

    #!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import Cookie
import os

backgroundColor = None
foregroundColor = None

form = cgi.FieldStorage();
if 'background' in form:
    C = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    backgroundColor = form.getvalue('background')
    C['background'] = backgroundColor
    print C

if 'foreground' in form:
    D = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    foregroundColor = form.getvalue('foreground')
    D['foreground']= foregroundColor
    print D



print """Content-Type: text/html

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Biweekly Task 3</title>
  </head>
  """

if backgroundColor:

    print """
    <body bgColor=%s>
    <form method="GET" action="http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/t3.py">
    </form>""" % (backgroundColor)


if foregroundColor:
    print """
    <body>
    <h1 style="color:%s"> Biweekly Task 3 </h1>
    <p style="color:%s"> Choose Background Color: <input type="text" name="background">
    <br/>
        Choose Foreground Color: <input type="text" name="foreground">
    <br/>
                   <input type="submit"></p>
    <form method="GET" action="http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/t3.py">
    </form>""" % (foregroundColor, foregroundColor)


else:
    print """
    <form method="POST" >
    <h1> Biweekly Task 3 </h1>
      <p>Choose Background Color: <input type="text" name="background">
    <br/>
        Choose Foreground Color: <input type="text" name="foreground">
    <br/>
                   <input type="submit"  value="Change"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
"""
</code>
</pre>
```

Can anyone tell me the problem and fix this code.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add `homework` to the tags.

Comment: You have to buffer all output until all your response headers (including setting cookies) are sent out.  Then you begin output.